# Layout in Fragment is not full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I don't know why but the layouts or contents in my fragment is not filling up the parent even though I have set the layout parameters in code and xml layout. Does anyone have a solution for this. Thanks in advance.
The image of my fragment is given below.
[image]

the shown image is done with recyclerview
recyclerview. xml
[image: recyclerviewlayout.xml]
fragment_items. xml
[image: itemsfragment.xml]
onCreateView of ItemsFragment. java class
[image: onCreateView of ItemsFragment.java class]

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: I have edited the question for you as you mention @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: sure I will. My lap is currently switched off because of power outage. I will check the answer as soon as my system is on. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I have tried the solution you provided. But I found my problem was not in those xml file but on the activity_main file.. thankyou for your reply @IntelliJAmiyan

Comment: I mean root layout. Set FrameLayout height match_parent.

Comment: Remove android:padding="24dp" from your root layout.

Answer (score 0):

[**`ConstraintLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups).

- Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

Your RecyclerView will be ( Respect to ConstraintLayout )

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply have the recyclerview in your fragment_items, you can use

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_videos"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```